# How can I search for duplicate questions?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, search

Duplicate questions are some of the most important to me because they have been asked multiple times. These will help me gain a better knowledge of the tag I'm in. They are also among the most frequently asked questions.

Now is there any way to search for these types of questions. I tried searching for

```
angular2 [duplicate]
```

but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: most of the time -you don't even have to - s.o., is smart enough to find them for you - most of the time, all you have to do is look at the right side column under *related*.

Answer (score 6):

There is a `duplicate` [search operator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), so

```
[angular2] duplicate:1
```

should [return](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular2%5D+duplicate%3A1) all of the questions tagged [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) and closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/315074/posts-that-are-the-target-of-the-most-duplicate-closures) for that (though it takes a while to run). It will return the most 'popular' duplicates first, the top results are:

- [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052)
- [What is the correct way to share the result of an Angular Http network call in RxJs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271899)
- [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311)

To get to the questions which were closed as a duplicate of one of these questions, use the 'Linked questions' section in the right sidebar.