# Duplicates while I did the search

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, search

Stack Overflow (SO) is a good source to find answers, as is the rest of the internet. So I'd search on google and when a SO page pops up I always check those question and answers.

When I will ask a question on SO I rephrase my question several times to check for duplicates. I'd like to spend time into asking a question so SO will not be cluttered with all the same questions. However, *never* I have succeeded.

Clearly I must be doing something wrong:

*Is anyone willing to spell out how to use this site so I minimise the duplicate question and thus I can motivate beforehand why it won't be a duplicate, or I won't post the question as it is already answered?*

This would save up your and my time.

Comment: If you're actually looking for duplicates before you post a question, even if it's a bad search you're already ahead of the curve. That said, I don't think anyone can really help you with googling, but hope I'm wrong and someone can!

Comment: relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254579/578411 (found that by searching for [`[faq] search`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfaq%5D+search)) also in the help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=search

Comment: Found this *after* I posted: [How can I search for duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340596/7880546); If it is usefull only time will show.

Comment: What might help is to include your research in your question as in: *I searched for "fubar" and that returned 'some result to foo a baz' but that didn't answer my question as I need to fu a bar*. Feedback on that will be that you either learn the correct terms or it will indeed prove that your question isn't a dupe. Also using google with `site:stackoverflow.com fubar` might return more results then when using the own sites feature. Also when asking your question you get duplicate suggestions: read them all before submitting your question.

Comment: also helpful : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 8):

> When I will ask a question on SO I rephrase my question several times to check for duplicates. I'd like to spend time into asking a question so SO will not be cluttered with all the same questions.

That's good. This is the type of effort that we expect from askers, and you are already doing that. So thank you.

> However, *never* I have succeeded. Clearly I must be doing something wrong.

I'm sorry to hear that. In some ways, I find that hard to believe. You mean to say that you've never managed to find an existing question on a subject, yet it's later been proven to you that there *is* a duplicate question because someone else found and proposed it?

While it's true that *sometimes* questions are hard to find for anyone but tag experts (both because they know the perfect search terms and, more likely, because they remember seeing and/or answering that question before), it shouldn't be so bad that someone putting in diligent effort can't find them.

Still, if that's true, then you have nothing to feel bad about. You are trying, and you obviously respect our time enough to search first. This is really all that we can ask of you, or anyone else. There is no magic.

There are almost certainly strategies you could learn and use to improve your search skills, but making recommendations along those lines are beyond the scope of this site.

About the only thing I can tell you is to avoid the search function built into Stack Overflow. It's terrible. Everyone uses Google site search (`site:stackoverflow.com`) to find questions here. The only time I ever use the Stack Overflow search is when I want to use some of its [advanced operators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), but that's pretty rare, and not especially useful when your goal is just to find duplicates.

> This would save up your and my time.

In fact, you may be doing us all a favor by asking these questions. Whatever do I mean? Well, if it's true what you say—that you are reasonably trying to find existing questions and failing—then obviously the existing questions are not easy enough to find. They either use obscure keywords, have bad titles, are improperly tagged, or *something* is wrong with them.

If your questions are reasonable and well-asked, then it isn't a problem for someone who knows of an existing question to mark it as a duplicate. Then, your question becomes a *useful redirect* to the other question. An answer that was previously hard to find because the question that contained it was so obscure now becomes easier to find.

As Joel Spolsky writes [here on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/):

> The more chance that someone types a question into Google and finds *their exact question* already answered, the better a job we’ve done.

In other words, duplicate questions themselves are not bad. Only two things are bad: (1) low-effort questions, and (2) scattering the information about across multiple questions. You are doing your part to prevent #1, so as long as the community does their part to avoid #2, we'll all be okay.

Comment: In my comment I left on the question I advise the OP to share where they searched for. I partly give that advice to prevent OP's from *only* stating that they searched a lot. Is *show your research* valid advice and if so, shouldn't that be mentioned somewhere in this answer? Casual readers might think they are OK by *only* Google-ing a lot.

Comment: I don't think that a lengthy discussion of a *failed* search effort is going to add much to the question. It's just noise. Better to get to the point. In other words, if your research is fruitless, there's little point in showing it. @rene

Comment: I never mentioned lengthy but my point is: If I do find search results but the OP mentioned none, I have to leave a comment: did you check [link] and based on how well that link matches the problem of the OP I leave a down vote as well. No research is my primary reason to down vote a question.

Comment: @rene And would that change if the question started by claiming that they did a search and presenting a bunch of inapplicable research? No, you're going to find the obvious link yourself, leave it in a comment, and downvote the question because it's obvious to you they didn't do enough research. Their claiming (or showing) otherwise won't change your mind, and shouldn't. (Lack of research effort is *not* my primary reason to downvote Qs, though. Research isn't even that important to me. I'm more concerned with the quality of the question itself. Not making sense is my primary reason to DV.)

Comment: In some ways, I don't understand lack of research as a downvote reason. I hardly ever come across questions that the answer cannot be found *somewhere* with enough research. That's part of the reason I don't ask many questions, I guess. The answers are out there for someone who is willing to find them. That doesn't make the question not useful, though. I understand it's a threshold. If there's *no* research done, I can understand wanting to downvote. But on the other hand, how much is enough?

Comment: Sure, that is a valid view point as well. The point is: *I searched a lot* is not very helpful if it turns out they typed *unicorns* in the searchbox while expecting *waffles*. But I guess I'll adjust my assume good faith filter and better watch for if questions make sense. Cheers.